# Is there something wrong limiting the DataContext to the ViewModel of the Window?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I don't feel comfortable letting any object being the DataContext of my views. As I'm following the MVVM pattern all windows have their own VM. What I plan to do is the following (taken from a window called Options):

```
    internal new OptionsVM DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            return (OptionsVM) base.DataContext;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.DataContext != value)
            {
                base.DataContext = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you see if I'm missing something or if this can be a bad idea due to something I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, hiding interface elements can lead to odd bugs.  For example, the following code will generate an `InvalidCastException`:

```csh
OptionsView view = new OptionsView();
Window window = view;
window.DataContext = new DifferentVM();
OptionsVM = view.DataContext;
```

It's a somewhat contrived example, but if you ever use WPF bindings to set an object's DataContext then similar scenarios are very likely.

I find it preferable to let the `DataContext` property exist as it was designed, and instead give my Views a constructor which accepts a data context in a more strongly-typed fashion.  In the View's code I also have a ViewModel property of the appropriate type:

```csh
public OptionsView(OptionsVM viewModel)
{
    DataContext = viewModel;
}

private OptionsVM ViewModel { get { return DataContext as OptionsVM; } }
```

Comment: I like you constructor approach but I don't agree with the View property. As I try to have the less the better on the code behind file making easier to code there is counterproductive.

Comment: How do you keep others from changing the datatype of the `DataContext` after the ctor executes?

Comment: You don't and can't. WPF's bindings system really doesn't want to be strongly typed, and there's no sense in fighting it. The ctor and property are really just glorified documentation for the humans' benefit.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I can see is if you use the construct

```
Window view = new OptionsView();

view.DataContext = ....;
```

then the DataContext will still be of type object - it requires you to always use a reference of the type of the view to see your strong typing

Comment: I agree but anyway until now I haven't needed to use the generic approach ... it's a bit ugly because at some places I planned to add some code on the property that won't get called if someone uses your approach ...

Comment: Ideally - you only touch the `DataContext` in the XAML bindings - you should avoid the need to manipulate the context in the code-behind. Good point though. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your approach should pose no dangers - if it makes it easier for you, enforce it. Just make sure that you comment why you chose to implement it this way. I am all for stronger data-typing over the base `Object` class. I think this actually makes it clearer what the supported context is.

Even using a constructor approach as suggested by @SeanU will not prevent others from changing the `DataContext` type after creation.

Comment: Have in mind that I'm calling base.DataContext so I'm not sure that what you say is true.

Comment: What advantages does this give you for MVVM? In your XAML bindings your types are agnostic anyway - it doesn't matter what the type is. It is not a good sign if you need to manipulate the `DataContext` from the code behind - right? I guess you are just looking for a way to restrict the type of object that can be handled with the `DataContext` - maybe not manipulate it.

Comment: Is just to have everything as hard-typed as possible to avoid mistakes.